# Java code generation at runtime: prevent creation of file "classlist.mf" in the working directory by javax.tools.JavaCompiler

Tags: java, java-compiler-api, javacompiler

When I run [java code](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/366) similar to this:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
...
CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, javaFileManager, diagnosticCollector, null, null, Collections.singletonList(fileObject));
task.call();
```

A file called `classlist.mf` appears in my working directory.

None of my sources contain the string "classlist". I am only using the standard `javax.tools` api's. That file contains exactly one (of the many) classes that I generated:

```
org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.generated.org.optaplanner.examples.common.domain.AbstractPersistable$getId
```

**How can I prevent that `classlist.mf` file from appearing in my working directory?**

Comment: Hey Geoffrey, you [posted a blog](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2018/01/09/JavaReflectionButMuchFaster.html) where you write `proper care needs to be taken that it doesn’t generate a classlist.mf file in the working directory`. Did you ever figure this out? If so, can you please answer your own question here?

Comment: No, I didn't figure it out (if I recall correctly). Because of this problem - and the bootstrap performance cost - I ended up going with LamdbaMetaFactory instead which is sufficient for my use case...